# Git Bash Not Supporting mkvirtualenv command

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, virtualenv, package

My installation of Ubuntu does not recognise the 'mkvirtualenv'command. I have checked the .bashrc file it appears to be standard however. Please if you may have time, suggest to me how to resolve that problem.

So After installing ubuntu (Beaver) using git bash and vagrant, my attempt to create a virtual environment using the command:

```
mkvirtualenv bugs --python=python3
```

Generates the OS response "command not found".

The steps I followed were:

1. Downloaded git bash and installed git bash
2. Downloaded virtual box and installed virtual box
3. From git bash, I create a work folder and then from within the folder generate an initial vagrant file by calling

   ```
   vagrant init
   ```
4. I edit the vagrant file and save as follows,

   ```
   Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

   config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"

   config.vm.network "forwarded_port", host_ip: "127.0.0.1", guest: 8080, host: 8080

   config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL

   sudo apt-get update

   sudo apt-get -y upgrade

   sudo locale-gen en_GB.UTF-8

   sudo apt-get install -y python3-dev sqlite python-pip

   sudo pip install --upgrade pip

   sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper

   if ! grep -q VIRTUALENV_ALREADY_ADDED /home/ubuntu/.bashrc; then

    echo "# VIRTUALENV_ALREADY_ADDED" >> /home/ubuntu/.bashrc

    echo "WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs" >> /home/ubuntu/.bashrc

    echo "PROJECT_HOME=/vagrant" >> /home/ubuntu/.bashrc

    echo "source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh" >> /home/ubuntu/.bashrc

   fi

   SHELL

   end
   ```
5. Start the virtual machine which installs the Ubuntu Beaver by calling,

   ```
   vagrant up
   ```
6. **During the installation of Ubuntu beaver, it flags that the ssh key is insecure and then reinstalls a set of new packages. After installing a series of Ubuntu and Python packages it finally completes.
7. Once Ubuntu is installed, start the ssh session as

   ```
   vagrant ssh
   ```
8. Navigate to vagrant by calling

   ```
   cd /vagrant
   ```
9. Attempt to generate the virtual environment by calling

   ```
   mkvirtualenv bugs --python=python3
   ```

This generates the error.

Any ideas where the problem may lie

Comment: Can you elaborate on your terminology? "Git Bash" is a port of the bash shell to Windows which comes packed in the [Git for WIndows](https://git-for-windows.github.io) installer. In your question, I fail to see any (direct) connection with Windows and GfW.

Comment: As to the essence of your question, please check whether `pip install virtualenv` does really install the `mkvirtualenv` script, and if yes, then where. I'd say if it installs it under `/usr/local/bin`, you'd need to have that directory listed in the `PATH` env. variable of that `ubuntu` user.

Comment: Yes we checked for the virtualenv.sh file using pip to (re)install. The file is located in /usr/local/bin. How would one go about editing the path of that ubuntu user; I followed the process in the URL listed below but that failed to register the file https://www.tumblingprogrammer.com/setting-up-windows-for-python-development-python-2-python-3-git-bash-terminal-and-virtual-environments/

Comment: Gosh, but that's the most basic knowledge about how a Unix-y OS works. I strongly recommend you (I mean those folks you referred to as "we") to have these basic backgrounds covered by a book or whatnot—otherwise this lack of knowledge will inevitably bite you in your rear as soon as you'll copy and paste random crap posted by a random know-nothing user. As to your immediate question, start [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/60218).

Comment: By the way you did not address in any way my original question regarding the terminology you have used in your question. Please do.

Comment: We included a reference to the PATH within the .bashrc but that failed to resolve the issue. Not certain your suggestion helps

Comment: The command is still not recognized after including in the path file. Nor is the command recognised when one changes directory into the file that contains the virtualenv.sh file

Comment: 1) You did it a wrong way. But I'm not sure where to start. Judging from this whole discussion, I'm afraid you should read [this](https://whathaveyoutried.com) thoroughly. 2) Your latter idea about changing of the directory is nonsensical due to the same lack of the most basic knowledge about how an OS works. Hence I'll stop now as I think my budget of willingness to help you is depleted as you show no signs of any desire to learn, sorry. Hope you'll get it sorted, somehow.

Comment: guess 18 years of linux doesn't count for much. thank you however